# Dealing with Sonata's admin final methods

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata

currently I have this code on my admin class. Since `getSubClasses` going to become final, this code must change. But HOW? Docs are lacking.

I tried doing `setSubClasses` in the constructor, but I also need the `user` object to calculate the classes, and it is not set yet in the constructor...

Basically how do I go about modifying these final methods because there doesn't seem to be a straightforward replacement.

```
public function getSubClasses()
{
    $subClasses = parent::getSubClasses();
    // ...some code...

    return $subClasses;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to extend an admin? https://symfony.com/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/current/reference/extensions.html  Or create a child admin? https://symfony.com/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/current/reference/child_admin.html

Comment: @ArleighHix I'm not sure. I just need a way to get rid of the final methods while still keeping the functionality. Decorators might work, but seem kinda too much. And I don't see how would the extension work here?

Comment: Hey sorry for the answer, my mistake. As I was saying I have the same issue dealing with finals. I tried to do Composition over Inheritance but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not sure if it's correct... Please reply if you know more about this solution.

I was trying to modify getDataSourceIterator() which on sonata 4 they made this method final.

AbstractAdmin.php on version 3

```
public function getDataSourceIterator()
```

AbstractAdmin.php on version 4

```
final public function getDataSourceIterator(): \Iterator
```

My class is extending the AbstractAdmin and trying to modify the getDataSourceIterator() but with version 4 is not possible cause of the final.

My example:

```
abstract class AbstractAppAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
```

and I changed to this

```
abstract class AbstractAppAdmin extends AbstractAdmin implements AdminInterface
```

Basically I implement the AdminInterface AGAIN (because is already implemented from AbstractAdmin) and that gives me the freedom to modify the method.

As I said might be bad idea but solved my issue.